# Ubuntu server - HDD external drive USB 3.0 unmounting

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb

I have got HP Thin Client T610 with Ubuntu Server on it. I connencted to this terminal my external HDD Drive WD 1.5TB. I mounted it, turned off USB autosuspend etc. and everything works okay, but only for a while after reboot.

After some time (sometimes 10 minutes, sometimes 1 hour), HDD disappears from my terminal. I check logs by `tail /var/log/syslog`:

```
Jun 17 11:27:39 terminal kernel: [  575.403505] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 08 6b 32 80 00 01 00 00
Jun 17 11:27:39 terminal kernel: [  575.403518] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 141243008 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Jun 17 11:27:40 terminal kernel: [  576.074623] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 17 11:27:40 terminal kernel: [  576.098837] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 17 11:27:40 terminal kernel: [  576.098848] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 08 6b b7 80 00 01 00 00
Jun 17 11:27:40 terminal kernel: [  576.098855] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 141277056 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
Jun 17 11:27:41 terminal kernel: [  576.794742] usb 4-2: reset SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 17 11:27:41 terminal kernel: [  576.819106] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jun 17 11:27:41 terminal kernel: [  576.819117] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 08 6b e4 80 00 01 00 00
Jun 17 11:27:41 terminal kernel: [  576.819124] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 141288576 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
```

(sdc is my external drive)

I thought I needed an active usb hub because the hard drive shuts down (This was happening on the Mac mini). I connected HDD to active hub, hub to USB 3.0 port in terminal and I connected 5V 2A power supply to my active hub. But now, system doesn't see hard drive or even USB 3.0 port.
`lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2412:2800  2.4G Composite Devic
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`find /dev/bus`

```
/dev/bus
/dev/bus/usb
/dev/bus/usb/002
/dev/bus/usb/002/002
/dev/bus/usb/002/001
/dev/bus/usb/001
/dev/bus/usb/001/001
```

`lsblk -a`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  29.8M  1 loop /snap/snapd/8140
loop1    7:1    0  30.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/7777
loop2    7:2    0  71.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/15564
loop3    7:3    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1705
loop4    7:4    0    55M  1 loop /snap/core18/1754
loop5    7:5    0  69.3M  1 loop /snap/lxd/15457
loop6    7:6    0         0 loop
loop7    7:7    0         0 loop
sda      8:0    0  14.9G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0  14.4G  0 part /
sdb      8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─sdb1   8:17   0 465.8G  0 part /mnt/sdb
```

Can someone help me? I've been fighting this for a week...

Comment: If the hard disk is having problems performing I/O, then it's not super uncommon for USB storage devices to become non-responsive and to see host-initiated resets like you're seeing. Power issues could also point at this, so the hub was a good call... Have you reviewed the drive's SMART data recently? Does the USB 3.0 root hub re-appear after a full power cycle? (shutdown and unplug all power and your hub) Does the USB 3.0 root hub disappear as soon as you connect your hub?

Comment: @Attie SMART said that drive is okay. USB 3.0 root hub re-appear after a full power cycle but only when my hub is disconnected and yes, root hub disappear when I'm connecting my hub.

Comment: It sounds like your hub is defective. It could be an issue with the hub's power supply... Is it a quality hub? Could you try: 1) disconnect the hub, 2) disconnect everything from hub (PC, power and peripherals), 3) reboot, 4) connect hub to PC only (no power, no peripherals). If this works, then 1) disconnect the hub, 2) reconnect power to the hub only, 3) reconnect hub... NOTE: I suspect that the HDD and hub issues are two separate / independent issues.

Comment: I test my hub with my mac mini and works properly. It's quality hub, I have second one for 2 years and it works great. When I disconnect hub from terminal and reboot it I can found device `Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub`. Then when I connect hub (without reboot) I can found my hub: `Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 4-Port USB 3.0 Hub`. Then when I connect my hard drive to this hub, system see this drive as usb device but I can't mount any partition...

Comment: Okay, I can mount partitions from HDD, my bad. I think that problem with hdd is lack of power, but other problem is my hub cannot connect with PC when it reboots and I don't know why :(